# What is a clean and quick way to use comparison operators on an MySQL field with a delimiter?

Tags: mysql, sql, operator-keyword, delimiter

For example, a field consists of two data, base level and job level, and are split with a delimiter.

> Field Name: 'baselvl:joblvl' 
>   Example Data: '70:30' => the entry signifies base level of 70 and a job level of 30

I'm trying to include a search in a PHP website to grab data that fulfills certain conditions. For example, grabbing data that has a base level of 70 or higher. Or, say, a base level greater than 50 AND a job level less than or equal to 30.

**Updated:**
I forgot to mention that they designed this field such that the joblvl part is optional.

> Example Data: '70' => the entry signifies base level of 70 and a job level of 0

And yes, I agree, the design isn't that great - but I can't change it. I have to work with how it is

Comment: The only "clean" way to do this is to redesign the table to store two different attributes in separate columns.

Comment: Yes, mysql. If I could change the way it was stored, I would - but I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

I think you are using **mysql**. Use the following query to split the column..

```
set @field='70:30';
select substr(@field,1,LOCATE(':',@field)-1) as baselvl,
substr(@field,LOCATE(':',@field)+1,length(@field)-LOCATE(':',@field)) as oblvl
```

**Please note that, the best way is to store both the values in separate columns, other wise you in run into lot of problems like this in future**

Comment: This works, thanks! Unfortunately, the joblvl part is optional... =\ For example, the data can be just '70' to show 70 base level and 0 job level. With your current code, it would set joblevel as 70 and base level as 0. Is there a way to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @temp varchar(30)='70:40'
Declare @temp1 varchar(30)='70:10'


if (
convert(int,substring(@temp, 0,charindex(':',@temp)))>=convert(int,substring(@temp,
0,charindex(':',@temp1)))
and 
convert(int,substring(@temp,
charindex(':',@temp)+1,len(@temp)))>=convert(int,substring(@temp1,
charindex(':',@temp)+1,len(@temp1))))
  print 'yes'
```